# Changing the outline color of a textarea

Tags: html, css

I know the standard is an orange outline for a textarea, but I want to change the color. How would I do that on my stylesheet? Would I apply it to the textarea:focus style also?

Answer (score 4):

```
​textarea:focus { outline: 1px solid blue; }​ /* Changes outline to blue */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS [outline](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) property (this is the property the Chrome browser uses to make elements have orange outlines), so for example:

```
myElement {
    outline: COLOR STYLE WIDTH;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outline property used with a value different than "none" should be applied to the ":focus" pseudo of an element. At least for me under Chrome

`textarea {outline: 1px solid pink}` 
doesn't work.